# Laravel Mix - Autoload modules with special characters in their name (eg. tippy.js or slick-carousel)

Tags: laravel, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

Is there any way to autoload packages with special characters in them?

I would like to extract npm packages using laravel mix and also set a global variable for the modules. When I use modules with special characters in them, mix.autoload() fails. I've posted a sample code below for reference.

```
mix.autoload({
        jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery'],        
        'tippy.js': ['tippy', 'window.tippy'],
        'slick-carousel': ['slick', 'window.slick'],
        'bootstrap-select': ['bootstrap-select'],
    }) 
   .extract(['jquery', 'slick-carousel', 'bootstrap-select', 'tippy.js']);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using Laravel Mix's alias feature.

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        modules: [
            'node_modules'
        ],
        alias: {
            slick: 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.js',
            tippy: 'tippy.js/dist/tippy.cjs.js',                
        }
    }
});

mix.autoload({
        jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery'],
        clipboard: ['ClipboardJS', 'window.ClipboardJS'],
        tippy: ['tippy', 'window.tippy'],
        slick: ['slick', 'window.slick'],        
    });
```